# Fontify (italic) text in agenda views

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, faces, todo, org-emphasis

I have some TODO headings with italicized text. These display correctly in Org buffers, but aren't fontified and italicized (slanted) when retrieved as part of an agenda view. Is there a way to ensure that `/foo/`, which is rendered as */foo/* in an Org buffer, is also displayed as */foo/* in an agenda view?

Comment: `org-mode` uses `font-lock`; whereas, `org-agenda-mode` uses `text-properties`.  The `text-properties` are applied during the data gathering from the `org-mode` files -- i.e., while searching using `org-search-view`, `org-tags-view`, `org-agenda-list`.  No one, except for me, likes to substantially modify and take over functions -- so I will not suggest hacking into `org-agenda-format-item` because everyone believes that this would be sacrilege.

Comment: For those people who wish to avoid touching the sacred internal functions such as `org-agenda-format-item`, one option would be to comb through the virtually finished `*Org Agenda*` buffer using a custom fix-up/touch-up function attached to the `org-agenda-finalize-hook` and modify the buffer after-the-fact so to speak.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at this soon and report back.

Comment: I would love to see any working examples anyone has been able to achieve.